# Calculating Sine in ASM

Tags: assembly, x86, irvine32

I am having major problems with my assignment. I am suppose to have the following:

•   The program must prompt for and enter an angle in radians.

•   Use a subroutine to compute sine of the angle using the first 10 terms of the Taylor Series.

I do not know how to effectively compute sine, as I have never had to before. I am not sure how to even simplify such a problem. I am getting a slew of errors in my code. Can I get a hand?

EDIT: I revised my code and the function I was using. I am now doing: `l_(i-1) * (-1)x^2/(2i)(2i+1)`.

EDIT2: I fixed the invalid code so it assembles, however I believe I am getting the wrong answer. Any suggestions on how to fix it?

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.data

negone      REAL8 -1.0
inputx      REAL8 ? 
one         REAL8 1.0
istu        REAL8 1.0
two         REAL8 2.0
inputa      REAL8 ?
inputb      REAL8 ?
inputc      REAL8 ?
result      REAL8 ?



prompt      BYTE    "Enter an Integer for X",0dh,0ah,0
resultPrompt BYTE   "The result of sine (your angle) is: ",0

.code
main PROC
loop1:
finit                   ; initializes floating point
mov edx,OFFSET prompt   ; offsets the prompt
call WriteString        ; writes prompt
call ReadFloat          ; read input of the value
fst inputx              ; save input of user
fmul inputx             ; Multiplies for X Squared
fmul negone             ; Multiplies X by negative 1
fst inputa              ; Inputs answer into inputa
mov eax, 2              ; move 2 into eax
fmul istu               ; Multiplies this by i
fst inputb              ; inputs answer into inputb
mov eax, 2              ; moves 2 into eax
fmul istu               ; multiplies that by i
fadd one                ; adds 1
fst inputc              ; places this into inputc
fmul inputb             ; multiplies input c with input b
fdiv inputa             ; divides whole by input a
fsub inputx             ; subtracts x
fst result              ; places this into result
mov eax, 0              ; moves i into eax
fadd istu
inc eax                 ; increments i
fst istu
cmp eax,10              ; compares i with 10
je endloop              ; if 10, end the loop
endloop:
mov edx,OFFSET resultPrompt ; offsets result
call WriteString        ; write prompt
call WriteFloat
call Crlf
call waitmsg
exit
main ENDP
END main
```

Comment: _"I am getting a slew of errors in my code."_ and you didn't manage to mention even one of them! Your code makes zero sense. PS: naming your variable `word` is a bad idea for multiple reasons.

Comment: @jester I am getting a ton of errors. Which one would you like for me to name? :/ Not being able to calculate Sine is the real issue at hand.

Comment: You start with the first one, usually :) Which part of the calculation causes you problem? I assume you have looked up the Taylor expansion, and it's just a bunch of multiplications and additions which I also assume you can do.

Comment: Yeah I mean I have the equation: sin⁡(x)=x-x^3/3!+x^5/5!-x^7/7!. I have no idea how I would use factorial.

Comment: Do you know what factorial is? Just repeated multiplication. To get from `1/n!` to `1/(n+2)!` just multiply by `1/(n+1)` and `1/(n+2)`

Comment: Hmm.. I think I understand you a little here. N would be a number the user specifies, and that would in turn get what im looking for?

Comment: `n` in my example was just a general placeholder to get from one term to the next. You will need 10 steps, it's specified in the assignment. The user enters `x`.

Comment: Looking at your conversation I think maybe you should look into something easier first to learn assembly basics.

Comment: @m0skit0 Unfortunately this is a HW assignment. Professor really turned up the heat on this one.

Comment: That usually means you missed classes or didn't practice enough :) I suggest you write a diagram with the algorithm then try to write the assembly for it.

Comment: @m0skit0 Honestly I just need a hand with writing this is all. I am not the only person have troubles with this assignment, and I have A's on all my other assignments. I am just having a bad time with this one because I have not taken calc or pre-calc yet.

Comment: Wait, how old are you, 11? Because "10 terms of Taylor" means sin(x) = x - x^3/3! + x^5/5! - x^7/7! ... - x^19/19!, and x = x^1/1!, so this is sum_i<1,10> of (-1)^(i+1)(x^(2*i-1))/((2*i-1)!) ... if you start with x^1/1! (i.e. x), the next member is previous adjusted by \*-1\*x\*x/(2i-2)/(2i-1)  ... i.e. three `fmul`, two `fdiv`, sum all, and some housekeeping instructions to have handy values around, like sum, single member, and (2i-1) incremented by 1 twice (between divisions). I mean, it may be tricky to write in x86 asm correctly, but the math behind is very basic add/mul/div, no calc.

Comment: Now I read your edits... so you got there on your own, ok. About what is wrong with your code... If you would indent the code from labels a bit, you would maybe notice you didn't do any loop at all, the `cmp eax,10` `je endloop` `endloop:` will end at next `mov edx,...` in any case, there's no other outcome for any `eax` value, it will either skip the `je` to it, or jump to it. There may be more errors in the code, as x87 stack-like nature may be tricky to correctly fill it up, keep going during calculation and pop everything at end, you should use debugger + single step to verify what it does

Comment: I upvoted for continuous effort, and communication, plus you are getting closer to a point of valid SO question, now you should debug your code and find out specific situation which is puzzling you, i.e. which instruction, which values are in registers, what happened in reality, and what you did expect and why and how it differs. Then we can easily explain you which of your assumption about particular instruction is wrong, but you can usually get that on your own by reading instruction reference guide. Wholesome Q "here is code, what's wrong" tends to get closed, or attract "all bad" answers.